# Continuous disk activity since upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 I have been experiencing continuous disk activity and the noise that goes with it (even when the machine is apparently unused). Any suggestions about how to diagnose / remedy this? Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you share a bit more info? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1110197/edit) your question and post the output of some commands like `iotop` and/or `htop`? You can install them with `sudo apt install iotop htop`.

Comment: Using iotop I noticed that firefox was frequently writing to disk.
I changed the browser.sessionstore.interval in about:config from 15 000 milliseconds to 300 000 milliseconds and rebooted.
So far the machine has been peaceful ...